# How to use npm script directly？

Tags: javascript, npm

A script in my package.json

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development PORT=3000 CODE_SPLIT=0 node ./react-imvc/bin/www-babel-register",
```

I need to start `--inspect`, for some reason, I can not modify the package.json, such as

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development PORT=3000 CODE_SPLIT=0 node --inspect ./react-imvc/bin/www-babel-register"
```

I want to use script directly, like this :

```
npm run "cross-env NODE_ENV=development PORT=3000 CODE_SPLIT=0 node --inspect ./react-imvc/bin/www-babel-register"
```

using `npm run script`, but it failed.

How can I use npm script like above?

Comment: use: npm run start

Answer (score 1):

assume that you want to run script with arg `--inspect` without changing the `package.json`:

```
npm run start -- --inspect
```

see:

```
$ npm run --help
npm run-script <command> [-- <args>...]

alias: run
```

Comment: Yes, it works. but I wonder that wheter can I just using `npm run "some script here, not start  build here but what they refer to" `

Comment: You can add `"someScript": "some script here, not start build here but what they refer to"` in `scripts` section including `start`, then just use `npm run someScript`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to execute the script you've got in your `package.json` which should look like this (after you've added the --inspect flag):

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development PORT=3000 CODE_SPLIT=0 node --inspect ./react-imvc/bin/www-babel-register"
}
```

This can be done by calling `npm run start`. Adding more scripts under another key lets you call them by using `npm run '.

Comment: node takes care of certain scripts like "run", "test" etc.. npm start should be fine.