# How do I run an npm script directly in VS code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, npm-scripts

I am trying to follow this [MS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/local-development).

So I install the CLI from the VS code terminal: *npm install @azure/static-web-apps-cli*

Works.

But following the instructions using "***swa init***" in the terminal I get this response:

*swa : The term 'swa' is not recognized....  etc.*

Adding the command to package.json as a script will work, but how do I run it directly from the terminal *[**without** adding it to package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273753/how-to-use-npm-script-directly)*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npx swa init` would pull the **swa** package and execute it as if it was run from within package.json. You can read more about it on [npmjs.com/package/npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx)

Alternatively, you could have the **swa** package installed globally with `npm i -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli`

Comment: Thanks..  Installing globally fixed it.. This info is missing in the MS docs..